# xsl:element does not want to accept strings coming from an attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to convert an element attribute value to a tag (name). Thus, for example, an `<test name="testname"/>` to a `<testname/>`. Mysteriously, it simply can not happen, I get the most various errors, among them

```
xsl:element: The value '$test' of the attribute 'name' is not a valid QName.
```

is the most important.

Minimal example, xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="test">
      <xsl:value-of select="/test/@name"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="$test"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to execute it on this test xml:

```
<test name="testname"/>
```

Why? I can do the same without any problem if `$test` is a hardcoded string. What is this "qname" thing and how can I generate it from an attribute value?

I am using xslt-1.0 with the xsltproc tool, I am considering on an upgrade (probably to xalan or more likely, saxon he). But I would like to solve this problem yet within xsltproc.

Comment: Xalan is not an upgrade to libxslt. Both are XSLT 1.0 processors.

Comment: Right. Then only saxon remains, I think a saxon-he could be compiled with graalvm to native code and it could be used in place of xsltproc.

Comment: Saxon has been compiled to native code with GraalVM in the form of SaxonC 12, for C/C++ you can download it from https://www.saxonica.com/download/c.xml, documentation is at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation12/index.html#!starting. For Python 3 there are even PyPi packages saxonche https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/,  saxoncpe and saxoncee.

Comment: Note that you also can run SaxonJS 2 with its command line package/tool `xslt3` anywhere where you have Node.js installed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3

Comment: That said, XSLT 1.0 is good enough for most applications - esp. with libxslt that supports a large number of extensions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks. I know that it is an option and that is my favourite in node.js environment. Currently I use xsltproc for basic command line tasks, because I do not want node.js dependence (and yet lesser a super-terrible jre or jdk dependence). I am surprised and very sad, why xsltproc development seems stagnating since a long ago, I also see that xsl standard is very good in its concepts but not so in its development, I still love it a lot. I think the major cause of that it is not used much more, are not these. I think, the major cause is that developers had simply a hard time to

Comment: go above the common procedural model. Also SQL suffered on it a lot, programmers simply could not grab the declarative concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an attribute value template `<xsl:element name="{$varname}">` or more general `<xsl:element name="{xpath-expression}">`.

Comment: Wow. It works. OMG why was it needed?

Comment: @peterh, well, you can use stuff like `<xsl:element name="newprefix:{local-name()}">` that way, if the attribute would be directly treated as a single XPath expression you couldn't do that. For future doubts as to what to use, check the XST spec e.g. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Creating-Elements-with-xsl:element indicates with `<xsl:element name = { qname } namespace = { uri-reference }` (i.e. the curly braces) that attribute value templates are expected. The text also clearly explains "The name attribute is interpreted as an attribute value template.".